# JDBC Update millions of records on Oracle database

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have a design issue. I have a database with millions of records which I need to update.

We will use JDBC because we have to do some processing to calculate new fields values.

It is a one go, and I will not need it any more. So I was thinking about something simple. I wanted to create new tables and delete the old ones, but the DBA do not want to, because the need for storage would be huge.

I will have to process about 80 millions rows, and for each row to update 3 fields.

Would a simple jdbc approach, with a setFetchSize(1000) for example, would work?

I mean select a, b, c from mutable for update;
then the update ...

Would a JDBC program be able to support the workload?

I was also thinking about using SpringBatch or EasyBatch. But I am wondering if it is worth investigating time in this for just one go (and some very short timelines).

What is your experience with this?

Comment: is the information needed to do the updates all contained in the database?  (formula's used) or when you said some processing has to be done, it's because some of the needed information for updates is local?

Comment: Hi. No the information for the update is not contained in the database. I have to read the data row, then call an external service to retrieve the calculated values, then update 3 fields of the rows with the calculated values.

Comment: @Gilles  How long do you have to accomplish this?  You are going to pull data into java and for each row, call an external service, then update the database.  Let's pretend you could get this done in 10ms per row, which I doubt you would be able to do, it will still take 9.25 days to complete the process.  Extend it up from there.  If it takes 100ms per row, now it is 92.5 days.  If it HAS to be done this way, you best be knowing what you are getting into.

Comment: Probably need to find a way to parallelize this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in JDBC. I would suggest something like the following:

- Create two or three threads. Each thread does the following
- Create a connection.
- Create a prepared statement that retrieves a disjoint subset of the rows
- Set the fetch size to 100 or so. Definitely less than 1000.
- Create an update statement
- Execute the query
- Iterate over the result set
- For each row add batch to update the row
- After fetch size rows execute the batch

Lets assume the fetch size is 100. The first execute will do a round trip which takes time. While that's happening go run another thread. When an execute returns processing the next 100 rows does not do a database round trip. The rows have already been fetched and the updates are being batched so this will not do a database round trip. After 100 rows execute the batch which will do a round trip and so will switch threads. Then it will fetch 100 more rows which will switch threads. I'm not sure whether two or three threads would be optimal but if I had to guess I'd try three.

But the above assumes the machine only has a single hardware thread which is not true. Most CPUs support 12 or more hardware threads so I would actually use 30 or so threads depending on what the hardware can support. Even with multiple CPUs you probably don't want more than 50 or so threads as that will start to introduce contention in the database.

The above assumes the external service is fast, much faster than the database. If not then processing each row is going to wait for the external service. In that case more threads. Since the updates will hit the database more slowly thread contention in the database is less of a concern.

One way to partition the query results into disjoint subsets is as follows:

```
SELECT c1, c2, etc, row 
FROM (SELECT c1, c2, etc, ROWNUM FROM ...) 
WHERE MOD(row, number_of_partitions) = ?
```

Then set the query param from 0 to number_of_partitions - 1, one for each thread. You have to do this as a subquery to get ROWNUM to work right.

Do not use updatable result sets. The performance will be abysmal, guaranteed.